# Default text appears on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, text

Actually i'm working on a wordpress website, which is related to school, i'm using universh WP theme which is purchased. I'm getting the below text as default:

> Want create site? Find Free WordPress Themes and plugins.

[image]

See, i've marked those words. Actually its a dynamic page, i've checked the core code. It's only the

> the_excerpt()

function. After that i don't have any idea, where it comes from. Also i've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901355/malicious-text-appears-in-all-pages-and-posts-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it) So please don't recommend that thread, its not working i've tried the way there mentioned.

P.S. Also the text will disappears when I login and try to edit the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What text editor You use ? Most easy way will be open folder with theme in some editor and search this string "Want create site? Find Free WordPress Themes and plugins." in all files - then You will know where they add it ... or You can check every file, because this string must be included somewhere, maybe in function.php  they add some modification to the_excerpt();

Answer (score 1):

I think when you ass content in post default editor then is not showing in `the_expert()` function
So you can add content in expert editor then after call `the_expert()` funtion

Answer (score 1):

Check that your theme is not using the [get_the_excerpt filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_excerpt) to prepend that phrase to all the excerpts.

Additional, if you only checked the files that load for that specific template, I would recommend that you run a search for that string for the entire theme. The source of the issue might stem from `functions.php` or even some JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1):

Please update the core files or update version of your WordPress. Use Latest one.