# WordPress malware / top:0; left:-9999px URL's

Tags: wordpress, security, spam, malware

I'm breaking my head for 2 days with this one, and would appreciate some extra thoughts.

These links are found in wp-content/cache/wp-rocket .html files only, while they are not present on the actual real-time pages.

I have tried searching in all files various strings: -9999, thewpclub, sorry_function. I searched through the database, but could not find anything at all.

WordFence & Sucuri are not finding any weird script within the files.

This was the closest problem someone had:

[Malicious text appears in all pages and posts. How do I get rid of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901355/malicious-text-appears-in-all-pages-and-posts-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it)

`<a href="https://www.thewpclub.net">Premium WordPress Themes Download</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.themeslide.com">Download WordPress Themes Free</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.script-stack.com">Download WordPress Themes</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.thememazing.com">Premium WordPress Themes Download</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.onlinefreecourse.net">free download udemy paid course</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.frendx.com/firmware/">download xiomi firmware</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://www.themebanks.com">Download WordPress Themes Free</a></div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-9999px;"><a href="https://downloadtutorials.net">udemy free download</a></div></div></div></div>`

Comment: Unfortunately, my friend, there isn't a "one size fits all" solution for these HTML/link injection hacks. It could be in a theme, in a plugin, in your database, in your WordPress Core Files, etc. I've seen ".png" files included in plugin footers that are actually PHP files, just named PNG, and included to cause malicious actions like this. Your best bet is to pay someone a nominal fee to clear it out, otherwise: Reinstall WP. Reinstall all plugins/themes. Change DB/Host/FTP passwords. Remove unused themes/plugins. Remove suspicious users, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I managed to solve it.

I know that "one size fits all" is not the case with malware. I asked for extra thoughts as someone might have a hint how to approach it as I'm well informed and capable of dealing with these situations through the years.

After numerous failed attempts to search various strings, trying to encode few words in hex and search those, searching through plugins etc. i inspected the cached `.html` file and noticed that these links were hidden under WooCommerce `delivery-info` div.

I then searched delivery-info string through all the WP files & I got around 50 hits. I found a suspicious line that one of the developers added, which was calling `delivery-info` div together with `$content` string.

I then searched `$content` string through all the plugins with numerous hits. After searching for a while I finally found the script that was causing it. It was hidden in WPBakery - js-composer/include/inc.php file which should not have existed. One of the lines from the file:

`$abc1 = '' . $divclass . '<a href="'.sanitize_context_zero("aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhld3BjbHViLm5ldA==").'">' . $array[array_rand($array) ] . '</a></div>';`

I deleted that file & then searched `inc.php` with a hit in `js-composer.php` calling for it.

Comment: Hi, I've got exactly the same malware links showing in my site. But no inc.php or js-composer.php. I'm using W3TotalCache, WPBakery and Yoast SEO though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue followed the steps Dorian did and I successfully removed the code from the pages.

The code in my case was in inc.php and was called by functions.php.

For anyone facing the same issue these are the steps i took to find the code.

I searched the wp-content files for "sanitize_context_zero" and got a hit for /themes/Newspaper/inlcudes/inc.php.
After that I searched for inc.php and got a hit on functions.php.

All of the modified files were in the parent theme not the child theme.